# PDF save in Oracle DB: ERROR - java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type: 71365

Tags: java, database, oracle, exception, sqlexception

I am trying to save PDF file in Oracle DB and using below code:

```
InputStream FILE_CONTENT = null;
Part filePart = req.getPart("pdf_file");
if (filePart != null ) {
    // prints out some information for debugging
    logger.info("File Name::"+filePart.getName());
    logger.info("File Size::"+filePart.getSize());
    logger.info("File Type::"+filePart.getContentType());

    // obtains input stream of the upload file
    FILE_CONTENT = filePart.getInputStream();

    //Insert Blob in Oracle DB
    cs.setBinaryStream(1, filePart.getInputStream(), (int) filePart.getSize());
}
```

and i am using **ojdbc14.jar**.
It is working fine for upto 30KB of PDF file but when i am trying to save more than 30KB file it showing error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Data size bigger than max size for this type: 71365
```

Please give me any solution to save PDF file in oracle DB.

Thanks.

Comment: ojdbc14.jar was indented for Java JRE 1.4 - which dates 2002( 17 years ago).

Comment: So i need to use ojdbc6.jar?

Comment: What is your database columns type?

Comment: Its BLOB which i use.

Comment: That should be fine.

Comment: I am currently facing this problem. I tried to use ojdbc6.jar also but still same issue occur.